# VB.net Navigating Text Adventure Game

Tags: vb.net, .net-4.6

I am working on a text adventure game. The goal of this program is to display three options and a textbox. The user can select one of the options by entering the corresponding number into a text box, which then is supposed to navigate the user into the next area, where the user is presented with another 3 options.

The issue I am currently having is navigating through the area game areas.

```
    Sub gameOver(ByVal DeathMessage)
        lblTitle.Text = "Game Over!"
        lblMain.Text = DeathMessage
    End Sub

    Sub pgMain()
        lblMain.Text = $"Enter 1 to start the game{vbCrLf}Enter 2 to quit the game"
        If aryInput(0) = "1" Then
            pg1()
        ElseIf aryInput(0) = "2" Then
            Me.Close()
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub btnSubmit_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnSubmit.Click
        aryInput(0) = tbxInput.Text
    End Sub

    Sub pg1() ' User picks a starting option
        lblTitle.Text = "You spot a secret magical lair do you"
        lblMain.Text = $"1. Enter the lair through the front door{vbCrLf}2. Enter the lair through the back door{vbCrLf}3. Wait untill midnight to enter the lair."
        If aryInput(0) = "1" Then
            MsgBox("Front door") 'pg2()
        ElseIf aryInput(0) = "2" Then
            MsgBox("backdoor")
            pg3()
        ElseIf aryInput(0) = "3" Then
            gameOver("You were mauled by wolves")
        End If
    End Sub

    'Sub pg2() ' User entered through the front door.
    '    lblMain.Text = $"1. Go to the chest{vbCrLf}2. Go to the bookshelf{vbCr}3. Go to the cauldron"
    '    If tbxInput.Text = "1" Then
    '        pg5() ' They went to the chest
    '    ElseIf tbxInput.Text = "2" Then
    '        pg6() ' User went to the bookshelf
    '    ElseIf tbxInput.Text = "3" Then
    '        pg7() ' User went to the cauldron
    '    End If
    'End Sub

    Sub pg3()
        tbxInput.Text = Nothing
        lblTitle.Text = "You were splashed with a poison spell do you"
        lblMain.Text = $"1. Cut off the infected part{vbCrLf}2. Drink a bucket of milk{vbCrLf}3. Inject yourself with some sort of medical syringe"
        If tbxInput.Text = "1" Then
            MsgBox("Infected Part") 'pg8()
        ElseIf tbxInput.Text = "2" Then
            MsgBox("Milk") 'pg9()
        ElseIf tbxInput.Text = "3" Then
            gameOver("You injected yourself with viper venom.")
        End If
    End Sub
```

As you can probably tell I am having issues with getting the content of the textbox to decide where the user will go next. I have tried using Input Boxes, and yes it works but they have a character limit and I would prefer figuring out a way to do this with a text box. I was also considering a way using key presses instead of a button click. Sorry for the beginner question, I am still learning my way around Visual Basic. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Where is aryInpur declared?

Comment: User input would be more reliable if you used radio buttons.  Just change the text on the radio buttons.

Comment: You are not giving the user a chance to type in the text box.

Comment: You are approached a WinForms application as if it was a Console application. WinForms is Event driven. Where are the events that trigger these subs?

Comment: Why event use an array? It seems you are only using the first element.

Answer (score 0):

I like radio buttons better because it is easier to control user input. A user can put anything in a text box and you need to handle the possibility that it is not 1, 2, or 3.

Initially `RadioButton3.Visible` is set to `False` at design time. It becomes visible if the user selects to start the game.

We kick the whole thing off in `Form.Load`. I declared a Form level variable to keep track of what page we are on, `PageNum`.

I have only set properties in the pgX subs. All the action is in the submit button. The first thing is to find which radio button is selected. The `GetSelectedRadioButton` returns the selected button or `Nothing`. You have to pass `Me` (which refers to the `Form`, the class where the code is running) as the container. Often radio buttons are found in a `GroupBox` or other container control so this allows for that.

You will need to write the code for `pg5`, `pg6`, `pg7`, `pg8`, and `pg9`. Also add `Case 5`,  `Case 6`, `Case 7`, `Case 8`, and `Case 9` to the submit button.

```
Private PageNum As Integer

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    pgMain()
End Sub

Private Sub pgMain()
    lblMain.Text = "Make a selection and click Submit"
    RadioButton1.Text = "start the game"
    RadioButton2.Text = "quit the game"
End Sub

Private Sub btnSubmit_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnSubmit.Click
    Dim rb As RadioButton = GetSelectedRadioButton(Me)
    If rb IsNot Nothing Then
        Dim Name = rb.Name
        Select Case PageNum
            Case 0
                If Name = "RadioButton1" Then
                    pg1()
                ElseIf Name = "RadioButton2" Then
                    Close()
                End If
            Case 1
                If Name = "RadioButton1" Then
                    MsgBox("Front door") '
                    pg2()
                ElseIf Name = "RadioButton2" Then
                    MsgBox("backdoor")
                    pg3()
                ElseIf Name = "RadioButton3" Then
                    gameOver("You were mauled by wolves")
                End If
            Case 2
                If Name = "RadioButton1" Then
                    pg5() ' They went to the chest
                ElseIf Name = "RadioButton2" Then
                    pg6() ' User went to the bookshelf
                ElseIf Name = "RadioButton3" Then
                    pg7() ' User went to the cauldron
                End If
            Case 3
                If Name = "RadioButton1" Then
                    MsgBox("Infected Part")
                    pg8()
                ElseIf Name = "RadioButton2" Then
                    MsgBox("Milk")
                    pg9()
                ElseIf Name = "RadioButton3" Then
                    gameOver("You injected yourself with viper venom.")
                End If
        End Select
    Else
        MessageBox.Show("Please make a selection.")
    End If
End Sub

Public Function GetSelectedRadioButton(Container As Control) As RadioButton
    Dim rb = Container.Controls.OfType(Of RadioButton)().FirstOrDefault(Function(r) r.Checked = True)
    Return rb
End Function

Private Sub pg1() ' User picks a starting option
    PageNum = 1
    lblTitle.Text = "You spot a secret magical lair do you"
    RadioButton1.Text = "Enter the lair through the front door"
    RadioButton2.Text = "Enter the lair through the back door"
    RadioButton3.Visible = True 'Set to False at design time
    RadioButton3.Text = "Wait untill midnight to enter the lair."
End Sub

Private Sub pg2() ' User entered through the front door.
    PageNum = 2
    lblTitle.Text = "You see a chest, a bookself, and a cauldron"
    RadioButton1.Text = "Go to the chest"
    RadioButton2.Text = "Go to the bookshelf"
    RadioButton3.Text = "Go to the cauldron"
End Sub

Private Sub pg3()
    PageNum = 3
    lblTitle.Text = "You were splashed with a poison spell do you"
    RadioButton1.Text = "Cut off the infected part"
    RadioButton2.Text = "Drink a bucket of milk"
    RadioButton3.Text = "Inject yourself with some sort of medical syringe"
End Sub

Private Sub gameOver(DeathMessage As String)
    lblTitle.Text = "Game Over!"
    lblMain.Text = DeathMessage
    RadioButton1.Visible = False
    RadioButton2.Visible = False
    RadioButton3.Visible = False
    btnSubmit.Visible = False
End Sub
```